# Как вызвать функцию, которая зарегистрирована в routers (DRF) при нажатии кнопки на HTML странице?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

имеется функция в файле views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'employee/index.html')
```

для неё определён адрес в файле urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from employee.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
]
```

и эту функцию я могу вызвать, нажав на HTML странице на кнопку(get запрос):

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}" class="button">button</a>
```

**Теперь суть моего вопроса:**

имеется функция в файле views.py:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from employee.models import EmployeeModel
from employee.serializers import DefaultViewSerializer

class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = EmployeeModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DefaultViewSerializer
```

пользуясь Django REST Framework я определяю адрес с помощью роутера в файле urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from employee.views import index, EmployeeViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('api', EmployeeViewSet, basename='employee')
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
]
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

**Как вызвать функцию по нажатию кнопки (get запрос) на HTML странице?**

пользуясь документацией к DRF пробовал такие варианты:

```
<a href="{% url 'employee' %}" class="button">button</a>
<a href="{% api-root %}" class="button">button</a>
<a href="{% employee-list %}" class="button">button</a>
<a href="{% employee-{url_name} %}" class="button">button</a>
<a href="{% employee-detail %}" class="button">button</a>
```

Возникает ошибка:

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 6: 'employee-EmployeeViewSet', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

не понятен какой должен быть синтаксис для вызова функции как в первом примере.

решения с использованием js и прочего не интересуют

Comment: Данная ошибка возникает при каждом варианте? Что за `index` в `urls.py`? Зачем вы указываете basename если не переопределяли get_queryset?

Answer (score 0):

В общем для меня это стало сюрпризом, но как оказалось, если в файле HTML в кнопке просто прописать адрес href вот так:

```
<a href="/api" class="button">Api</a>
```

то выполнится та ф-ция или класс, который указывается в файле url.py:

```
router.register('api', EmployeeViewSet)
```

а basename здесь вообще ни при чём, это для чего-то другого, чего я пока не практиковал.